# Kerberos SSO Not working after Chrome Update

Tags: google-chrome, single-sign-on, kerberos

We use Kerberos SSO for our SAP Business Objects Application and after the last week's Chrome upgrade to version 101.0.4951.54, the SSO stopped working on chrome, but it still works fine in IE11. Has anyone else experienced and found solution?

P.S - I see another user posted the same question with different application but I couldn't ask the user if he/she found the solution becuase I am new to this forum and haven't earned privilege to comment on others questions.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved.

It is because of Security Policy parameter name change in new Chrome browser. https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408#noNonIncl

Chrome version 101 has removed the policy name "AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist" and replaced with "AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist".

Fixed the issue by replacing "AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist" with "AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist" under registry Editor

Example: Key: \Software\Policies\Google\Chrome
Element Type: String (REG_SZ) Element Name: AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist Element Value: .mycompany.com,.trustedcompany.com